# Refactoring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

Here is my code:

```
var randomColor = ["red", "blue", "green", "#9CBA7F", "yellow", "#BF5FFF"];

function setRandomColor() {
 return randomColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColor.length)];
}

$('.mastermind_master_cpu').each(function() {
 $(this).find('td').each(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", setRandomColor);
 })
})
```

As you can see, the mastermind_master_cpu table will randomly fill with different background color. The problem is I have ten different tables and am repeating this every time. Does anyone know how I can go about making this just one function / variable and calling it when needed?

Thanks!

Comment: consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com as a better place for this question.

Comment: ...though I don't know where your repetition is coming from. Looks to me like you're iterating different tables right now.

Comment: And you seem to be missing the point of passing a function to `.css()`. The point is that it iterates a collection, but you're passing it to a collection with a single element. Why not `$(this).find("td").css("background-color", setRandomColor)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class, say `random_color`, to apply to each table in addition to your current class, like this:

```
<table class="mastermind_master_cpu random_color">...</table>
```

Then you can just use this once:

```
$('.random_color').each(function() {
 $(this).find('td').each(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", setRandomColor);
 })
})
```

But as [*cookie monster*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274884/refactoring-in-javascript/23274948#comment35622301_23274884) points out, this can be done much more succinctly:

```
$('.random_color td').css("background-color", setRandomColor);
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/v6PNs/)

Comment: Aren't you just doing the same thing but with a different class?

Comment: ...oh, maybe each table has a unique class right now. That's weird.

Comment: @cookiemonster That's what I suspect to be the issue.

Comment: thanks a ton guys. this works. p.s.w.g was correct, each table had a unique class.